# Change Password Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, change-password, clientcredential

I have been able to create Azure Functions App to manage Azure B2C Users. I can create new users, and update profiles flawlessly using the client_credentials Flow. However, when I change the password  using a PATCH request with body:

```
{
  passwordProfile: {
     password: 'password-value',
     forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: false
     },
  passwordPolicies: "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

I get this error:

```
 {code: 'Authorization_RequestDenied', message: 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.'}
```

I have done some research on this, and figured out that updating password requires Delegated Permission "Directory.AccessAsUser.All". From the Front End Application, I am signing in using the B2CLogin Flow, therefore the access token is not compatible with Graph API. Also, "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" does not exist at the Application level in the B2C application. Therefore, I cant use the Patch Request with the client_credentials Flow as well. According to some suggestions, the process can be done by Azure AD PowerShell by assigning "Company Administrator" Role. But, I have not found a solution to reset password through the Azure Function. A step-by-step solution(if it exists) would be really helpful for me as I am relatively new to Azure Services.

Comment: Please provide a correlation id and timestamp of error message and also  you need to send value in password:value please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#password-profile-property)

Comment: add-azureaddirectoryrolemember -objectid <servicePrincipalObjectId of App Reg client creds are for> -roleid helpdeskadmin-role-objectId

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to assign the **Global Admin** role to the service principal on Azure portal.

Go to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) - **Azure Active Directory** - **Roles and administrators**.

Search for "Global admin" and select it.

[image]

Click on **+Add assignments**. And then search for your service principal.

[image]

Please note that "Applications are allowed for active assignments only.".

So after clicking on "Next>", select "Active" for the Assignment type.

[image]

After the assignment is finished, you are able to update the password using client_credentials flow.

[Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0) which is mentioned by @Jas Suri can also do the same thing.

Comment: worked but used Helpdesk administrator to give less priviledges to the application